# Can't access parent class enum from outside

Tags: c++, class, enums

I want to access my Class' enum which inherited from it's base class but it gives error.

Says I must use `Base::One`, not `Extended::One`.

But **another people don't know about the Base class**, they just know the Extended class which I published with them.

How can I use `Extended::One` to access all the base class' enums?

```cpp
class Base {
    public:
    enum Type {
        One,
        Two
    };
};

class Extended : Base {

};

int main() {
    Extended::One; // ERROR: constant Base::One is inaccessible

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Very related question about the differences between public, protected and private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Missing "public" in inheritance, so voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accidentally using [private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance). To fix this, define `Extended` as follows:

```cpp
class Extended : public Base {

};
```

Comment: oh my god, I couldn't see that for 20 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Type might be public in Base, but Base itself is not a public base class of Extended, so your main function doesn't know about it.

Why not define the enum in the global scope if other classes need to use it?